# How to split a returned List<String> by comma from a text file?

Tags: java, list, bufferedreader, filereader

I'm reading from a  text file (`usernames.txt`) which has values separated by commas:

> AA328747, AA337748, AA057393, AA290457, AA467620, AA225950, AA352105,
>   AA108183, AA057070,

using my method:

```
public static List<String> readUsername(String path){

        File file = new File(path);     
        Reader fileReader;
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String username;

        try 
        {
            fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            username = br.readLine();

            while (username != null)
            {
                list.add(username);
                username= br.readLine();
            }

            br.close();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           

        return list;        
    }
```

And I try to print it out to console:

```
List<String> usernameList = readUsername(fileStr);

    for (int i=0; i < usernameList.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(usernameList.size());
        System.out.println(usernameList.get(i) + " end");
    }
```

where `fireStr` is just my path file string.

And it prints well but the size of the list object (`usernameList.size()`) is only `1`.

The print out is:

> AA328747, AA337748, AA057393, AA290457, AA467620, AA225950, AA352105,
>   AA108183, AA057070,  end

How I want it to print out is like:

> AA328747 end
>
> AA337748 end
>
> AA057393 end
>
> AA290457 end
>
> AA467620 end
>
> AA225950 end
>
> AA352105 end
>
> AA108183 end
>
> AA057070 end

And the list size should be more than `1` items (In my example it should be `9` for nine usernames in the text file).

How do I get rid of the commas and just evaluate each username as separate strings instead of one big string?

Comment: I think you're looking for the `split()` method

Comment: `String::split`

Comment: Like this `usernameList.get(i).split(",")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want the [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method. You can use [`Collections#addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll(java.util.Collection,%20T...)) to directly add all the elements from the `Array` produced by `split` to the `List`:

```
while (username != null)
{
     Collections.addAll(list, username.split(","));
     username= br.readLine();
}
```

Comment: I thought this was the more elegant answer between the two responses I got.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Update your function `readUsername` as below.

```
while (username != null) {
     List<String> tmp = Arrays.asList(username.split(","));
     tmp.removeIf(u -> u.isEmpty());
     list.addAll(tmp);
     usernames = br.readLine();
}
```